# Mute application volume in win CE

Tags: windows-ce

I have developed a media based application that runs on a device with Win CE. I need to have a mute/unmute button for controlling the application volume. I have developed the app using .Net compact framework.

Answer (score 3):

I've used waveOutSetVolume for mute in WinCE:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/waveOutSetVolume.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the sound volume for certain application. What you could do is define a static `Mute` `boolean`. When it's set to `true`, the sounds are not being played.

OR

You could look for a custom library that allows playing audio files and controlling the volume - anyway, this isnt the case, if you are only interested in mute/unmute.